# Data Factory - How to compare two GetData Acitivies in If condtion

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to add two conditions ( scpecificly the condition "or" ) to check the file size of two getdata activity as evidences bellow:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to compare these two get metadata activitie condition?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try using the 'or' function   @or(lessOrEquals(.....), lessOrEquals(.....)) .  By the way, above both lines are referencing the same activity so you will want to fix that.

Comment: Hi @ScottMildenberger , I've tryed but did ot works to me.. could you send me mor details?

Comment: so you tried what was in my comment?  What didn't work, did you get error or what?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger

I've tried : @lessOrEquals(activity('Sizing Fertilizer').output.size,10)

@or(lessOrEquals(activity('Sizing Fertilizer_copy1').output.size,10))

but the first line I have de error like : output:any

GetMetadata activity output

The function call must take the completion string(13)

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Mildenberger suggested to compare two, get metadata activities use the expression like below

```
@or(lessOrEquals(activity('Get Metadata2').output.size, 10),lessOrEquals(activity('Get Metadata3').output.size,10))
```

**The OR expression should be in the form of `or(<expression1>, <expression2>)`  to execute.**

[image]

**Output:**
If activity performs its inner activity base on comparison result:
[image]